# Finding percentage change in prices between rows

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, playframework

I have been trying (to no avail) to formulate an SQL query that will return rows with the greatest change in pricing between the most recent entry and the first entry greater than 1 day previous.

Price scraping takes a non-trivial amount of time due to a large data set, so times between first and last rows for one pull will often be ± many minutes. I would like to be able to pull the first record from `x` time or greater ago, pseudo `SELECT price FROM table WHERE date < [now epoch time in ms] - 86400000 LIMIT 1 ORDER BY date DESC`

My table format is as follows: (date is epoch time in milliseconds)

```
 itemid     price         date  ...
-----------------------------------
     ... most recent entries ...
    1       15.50     1373022446000
    2       5.00      1373022446000
    3       20.50     1373022446000
     ... first entries older than X milliseconds ...
    1       13.00     1372971693000
    2       7.00      1372971693000
    3       20.50     1372971693000
```

I would like to have a query that returned a result something similar to the following

```
 itemid      abs       pct
----------------------------
    1       +2.50     +19.2%
    2       -2.00     -28.6%
    3        0.00      0.00%
```

I'm not sure how to approach this. It seems as though it should be able to be done with a query, but I've been struggling to make any progress. I'm running sqlite3 on Play Framework 2.1.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with correlated subqueries and joins.  The first problem is identifying the most recent price.  `tmax` helps with this by getting the latest date for each item.  This is then joined to the original data to get information such as the price.

Then a correlated subquery is used to get the previous price as least xxx milliseconds before that date.  Note this is a relative time span, based on the original date.  If you want an absolute timespan, then do date arithmetic on the current time.

```
select t.itemid, t.price - t.prevprice,
       (t.price - t.prevprice) / t.price as change
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.price
              from yourtable t2
              where t2.itemid = t.itemid and
                    t2.date < t.date - xxx
              order by date
              limit 1
             ) as prevprice
      from yourtable t join
           (select itemid, max(date) as maxdate
            from yourtable t
            group by itemid
           ) tmax
           on tmax.itemid = t.itemid and tmax.maxdate = t.date
     ) t
```

If you have a large amount of data, you might really consider upgrading to a database other than SQLite.  In any event, indexes can help improve performance.

Comment: This seems to work great, thank you! I've been considering changing databases, as the amount of data we're seeing is increasing. I'll have to scout out options.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you want the diff and % between the first price and the last price for each `itemnid`.

I think this will help you:

```
select
 t1.itemid,
 (select top 1 price from table tout where tout.itemid = t1.itemid order by date desc) - 
 (select top 1 price from table tout where tout.itemid = t1.itemid order by date) as dif,
 ((select top 1 price from table tout where tout.itemid = t1.itemid order by date desc) - 
 (select top 1 price from table tout where tout.itemid = t1.itemid order by date)) /
 (select top 1 price from table tout where tout.itemid = t1.itemid order by date desc) * 100 as percent
from
table t1
group by t1.itemid
```